# How to detect Excel version programmatically

Tags: excel, registry, version

In my installer, I checked the registry key (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Application\CurVer) to get version of Excel.
It has worked since day 1. 
However, recently we find on one client's PC there is no such key and my installer fails.
So I wonder if there is any other registry key to get version of Excel? 
Or the client's Excel has some issue?

Thanks

Edit

The client has office 2010 (32 bit), windows 7 (64 bit).

Comment: You don't provide any relevant details (Office version? OS?) on the failing PC, so it's difficult to make any suggestion.

Comment: oh, thanks for reminding. Updated the post with OS, office version

Comment: "Or the client's Excel has some issue?" - that's quite possible...

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub dural()
    MsgBox Application.Version
End Sub
```

Which on my machine yields 12.0 for Excel 2007

Answer (score 1):

Using `Application.Version`

```
Sub Excel_Version()

Select Case (Val(Application.Version))

Case 8
        MsgBox "You use Excel 97"
Case 9
        MsgBox "You use Excel 2000"
Case 10
        MsgBox "You use Excel 2002"
Case 11
        MsgBox "You use Excel 2003"
Case 12
        MsgBox "You use Excel 2007"
Case 14
        MsgBox "You use Excel 2010"
Case 15
        MsgBox "You use Excel 2013"
End Select

    MsgBox "Welcome to Microsoft Excel version " & _
    Application.Version & " running on " & _
    Application.OperatingSystem & "!"

End Sub
```